# FreeBSD, update UEFI boot after motherboard change

Tags: freebsd, uefi

I had a FreeBSD 10 installation that booted under UEFI. It's on an AsRock C2750D4I motherboard. Recently I've had the motherboard replaced under warranty and now I can't boot the server automatically.

If I use the boot menu and select the UEFI shell I can change to fs0:/efi/boot and run the bootx64.efI - which then boots successfully into FreeBSD.
Any idea what I might need too do to get the server to boot without manual intervention?
I'll be upgrading to FreeBSD 11.1 too if that makes things simpler.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but you can look into `gpart bootcode` command.

Comment: That didn't work for me, I think the bootcode option is only used for legacy booting.

Answer (score 0):

Does your /efi/boot also contain a `startup.nsh` file?

Once booted, look at: `gpart show`

Find the number of the EFI partition:
`gpart bootcode -p /boot/boot1.efifat -i <that number here> <name of disk, like ada0 or da0>`

This will update your EFI boot code with the newer code.